# apache .htaccess file on lighttpd

Tags: apache, .htaccess, lighttpd

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^packed\.js$ pack.php?debug=0 [nc]
RewriteRule ^debug$ pack.php?debug=1 [nc]
```

That worked fine on apache in a .htaccess file placed in a specific directory. If I want to do this on lighttpd, do I have to add it in the config file or something?

Would I need to make any changes to these rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

lighttpd doesn't support `.htaccess` files like Apache httpd does. That's where the "light" in "lighttpd" comes into play.

You can, however, migrate these rules from Apache httpd's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to lighttpd's [mod_rewrite](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModRewrite). But be aware that the `NC` flag (case-insensitive matching) is *not* supported by lighttpd's mod_rewrite. If you are fine without it, you could simply use the following rewrite rules:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    "^packed\.js$"  => "pack.php?debug=0",
    "^debug$" => "pack.php?debug=1" 
)
```

If you need the match to be case-insensitive, you'll probably need to invoke [mod_magnet](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModMagnet) and a custom Lua script.

Comment: lighttpd uses pcre regexes, so `(?i:...)` is supported, e.g. case-insensitive matching of "debug": `"^(?i:debug)$" => "pack.php?debug=1"`