# nette, lighttpd - url rewrite?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, lighttpd, nette

I am new to the Nette Framework and have no experience with URL rewriting, so I apologize for my question.

The default syntax of Nette's router is:

```
<presenter>/<action>[/<id>]
```

so URLs are in format `localhost/mypage/articles/view/35`

My question is how to configure lighttpd to accept these urls and bind them to valid content?

I found only configuration for Apache in the documentation: http://doc.nette.org/en/2.1/troubleshooting#toc-how-to-allow-mod-rewrite

Comment: you need htaccess equivalent fot lighttpd - see [similar question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654765/apache-htaccess-file-on-lighttpd

Answer (score 0):

try using [magnet-module](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModMagnet) + [lua](http://www.lua.org/docs.html) script

add magnet module to the lighttpd modules

```
server.modules = (
...
        "mod_magnet",
...  
)
```

lighttpd virtual host example:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(example.com)$" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/example.com/document_root"
    magnet.attract-physical-path-to = ( server.document-root + "/rewrite.lua" )
}
```

create rewrite.lua file in the document_root folder (according to the setting above)

```
attr = lighty.stat(lighty.env["physical.path"])
if (not attr) then
    lighty.env["uri.path"] = "/index.php"
    lighty.env["physical.rel-path"] = lighty.env["uri.path"]
    lighty.env["physical.path"] = lighty.env["physical.doc-root"] .. lighty.env["physical.rel-path"]
end
-- uncomment below for debug output to stdout
-- print ("final file is " ..  lighty.env["physical.path"])
```

credit for this post goes to 'edke' user from [nette forum thread](http://forum.nette.org/cs/1953-routovanie-a-lighttpd)

could be worth trying also this (or get inspired): http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2008/05/24/clean-urls-permalinks-for-wordpress-on-lighttpd/